# Dynamically processing multiple batch files and generating corresponding output files with Spring Batch

Tags: csv, spring-batch

I've recently started learning Spring Batch in order to make use of some of its more advanced features like asynchronous batch processing, job stopping, and scheduling to replace some existing batch processing functionality, and implement new batch processing functionality.  Right now, I'm trying to figure out how to dynamically process multiple batch files and generate a "receipt" file for each input file, and I'm confused by some of the design decisions of the Spring Batch architects.  It seems like in order to process a simple flat CSV file and generate the output, I'm going to have to manually hack the beans in my ApplicationContext and manually set their "resource" properties at runtime in order to achieve what I want with the FlatFileItemReader and FlatFileItemWriter.  This is neither safe nor good practice for something that is allegedly a multi-threaded, high-performance batch processing framework.  Am I just missing something ?

Comment: I've answered the question of the property hacking : the beans related to a Job can be made unique to a JobInstance by using scope="step" on the beans, which is an addition to the Spring Framework contributed by Spring Batch, but I'm still looking for an easy way to map 'n' input batches to 'n' output batches.

Comment: Alex are you still looking for an answer to your question of how to make a generic job to handle multiple source files and output your receipt file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I was misunderstanding some of the documentation.  Spring Batch introduces a new bean scope, "step" and uses that to create new beans for each step in a batch flow based on the bean with the name given in the configuration for the readers and writers.  It then dynamically configures these using Spring's EL.  As for getting the multiple batches going, I just wound up doing the configuration for a single batch definition, then pushing the multiple batch handling into code.

Comment: can you please help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878122/dataloader-using-spring-batch-partitioning

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you might use the `MultiResourceItemReader` to specify multiple resources and set the `FlatFileItemReader` as  `MultiResourceItemReaders` delegate.

Comment: I had actually looked at doing that, but there's no (convenient) way to multiplex output files from input files.